# T flip flop VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, flip-flop

I am learning VHDL and I ran into the following code:

```
Entity fft is 
  port (t, r: in bit; q: out bit);
End  entity;

Architecture fft_df of fft is
signal state: bit :='0';

Begin

state <='0' when r='1' else
         not state when t='0' and t'event else
         state;

q<=state;

End;
```

Well, my doubt is about what this code does and if or not this is a  behavioral or dataflow description of a T flip flop with reset.
And than, which is the meaning of `not state when t='0' and t'event`? (I suppose the T flip flop works on falling edge).

Thanks to all.

Comment: There are two processes in your code, because signal assignments are processes. The code itself looks like a quite unusual description of a register with asynchronous reset. But this is not a good coding style in my eyes.

Comment: I meant, this is a data flow description (fft_df stands for t flip flop data flow) and works on falling edge.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get a useful answer if you follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What exactly is your question?

Comment: I just need to understand what the code above does and if that code is a VHDL dataflow approach. @MatthewTaylor

Comment: So, please could you edit your question to correct your typo?

Comment: I wouldn't get too hung up about whether code is "dataflow" or "behavioural". There is a trade off between the level of abstraction (the higher the level of abstraction, the easier it is to write, read and maintain the code) and performance (the lower the level of abstraction the higher the performance of the resulting logic in terms of speed or area). It's engineering; engineering is all about trade-offs. You will probably find [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682019/confusion-between-behavioural-and-dataflow-model-programs-in-vhdl) useful.

Comment: I agree with you @MatthewTaylor, but what I have learnt about VHDL, is that a behavioural description requires a process statement with a sensitivity list (optionally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm missing the clock input. A T-flipflop (with asynchronous reset) would actually be described by

```
entity tff is 
    port (clk, reset, t: in bit; q: out bit);
end entity;

architecture rtl of tff is begin
    q <= '0' when reset = '1' else
        not q when rising_egde(clk) and t = '1';
end;
```

Or more commonly written as:

```
architecture rtl of tff is begin
    tff_proc : process(clk, reset) begin
        if reset = '1' then
            q <= '0';
        elsif rising_egde(clk) then
            if t = '1' then
                q <= not q;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end;
```

p.s. reading an output requires compiling in VHDL-2008 mode.